# Solr Language Detection using DataImportHandler

Tags: solr, import

In my Solr configuration files I have defined a DataImportHandler that fetches data from a Mysql database and also processes contents of PDF files that are related with registers of the SQL database. The data import works fine.

I'm trying to detect the language of text contained in the files during the data import phase. I have specified in my solrconfig.xml a `TikaLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory` as explained in https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection and have defined in my document schema the language fields, nevertheless, after I run the indexation from the Solr admin, I cannot see any language field on my documents.

In all the examples I have seen, language detection is done by posting a document to solr with the post command, is it possible to do language detection with a DataImportHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have defined the UpdateRequestProcessor chain, you need to actually specify it in the request handler (DataImportHandler's in this case). You do that with *update.chain* parameter.

Also, ensure that you include [LogUpdate and RunUpdate processors](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors#UpdateRequestProcessors-Customupdaterequestprocessorchain), otherwise you are not even indexing at all.